# TikZ: posticipate execution of type /.code key

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, pgf-core

I'm trying to create some TikZ keys which allows to easily draw distributed loads on a mechanical structure (or truss). The code I wrote at the moment is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{load start/.style={insert path={coordinate (mec@start@load)}},%
         load end/.style={insert path={coordinate (mec@end@load)}},
         load distance/.initial=1em,
         force distance/.initial=10pt,
         force length/.initial=.7cm}
\tikzset{forze/.code={%
    \coordinate (mec@X1) at ($(mec@start@load)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/load distance}!90:(mec@end@load)$);
    \coordinate (mec@X2) at ($(mec@end@load)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/load distance}!-90:(mec@start@load)$);
    \draw (mec@X1) -- (mec@X2);
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{mec@X1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{mec@X2}{center}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mec@force@distrib@lenght}{veclen(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mec@force@number}{round(\mec@force@distrib@lenght/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/force distance})}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mec@force@distance}{1/\mec@force@number}
    \pgfmathparse{1-\mec@force@distance}
    \foreach \i in {0,\mec@force@distance,...,\pgfmathresult}{
      \coordinate (endarrow) at   ($(mec@X1)!\i!(mec@X2)$);
      \coordinate (startarrow) at ($(endarrow)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/force length}!90:(mec@X2)$);
      \draw[-latex] (startarrow) -- (endarrow);
    }
    \coordinate (endarrow) at   ($(mec@X1)!1!(mec@X2)$);
    \coordinate (startarrow) at ($(mec@X2)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/force length}!-90:(mec@X1)$);
    \draw[-latex] (startarrow) -- (endarrow);
  }}%}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1mm]
\coordinate (a) at (0,0) node[left=of a]{A};
\coordinate (b) at (0,3) node[left=of b]{B};
\coordinate (c) at (3,3) node[right=of c]{C};
\coordinate (d) at (3,0) node[right=of d]{D};
\draw[thick] (a) -- (b) [load start] -- (c) [load end] -- (d);
\path[forze] (a);
\draw (d) [load start] -- (b) [load end];
\path[forze] (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1mm]
\coordinate (a1) at (0,0) node[left=of a1]{A1};
\coordinate (b1) at (0,3) node[left=of b1]{B1};
\coordinate (c1) at (3,3) node[right=of c1]{C1};
\coordinate (d1) at (3,0) node[right=of d1]{D1};
\draw[thick] (a1) -- (b1) [load start] -- (c1) [load end,forze] -- (d1);
\draw[forze] (a1) -- (d1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The `load start` and `load end` keys are used only to save the beginning and ending coordinates of the distributed load, and the `forze` key uses these coordinates and draws in the right way the baseline and all of the arrows. In the first example everything works fine but, as you can see, to get the right output it is necessary to define another path (after the one in which `load start` and `load end` are used) where the `forze` key is used.

In the second example I show the syntax I would like to use (basically I want to avoid the necessity to define the second "fake" path) but you can see that something is wrong:

- In the first case the arrows appears, but the specificed path is disappeared (the structure disappears);
- In the second case the path is there (the line from `d1` to `a1`) but the arrows are overimposed to the previous ones.

I think that this happens because the code defined in the `forze` key is processed too early, when the start and end coordinates of the load are not yet correctly saved.
I tried to use the `append after command`, `execute at end to`, `execute at end note` keys, but the result is always the same. Is there a better approach?

An additional question: is it correct to define macros (like `\mec@force@number`) via `\pgfmathsetmacro` within a key (like `forze`) or it should be better to define them outside it? Which is better from a "register consumption" point of view?

### Update

As @percusse suggested, I tried to use the `preaction` and `postaction` keys. I tried those possibilities:

```
\draw[postaction={forze}] (a) -- (b) [load start] -- (c) [load end] -- (d);
```

Perfect result

```
\draw[thick,postaction={forze}] (a) -- (b) [load start] -- (c) [load end] -- (d);
% or
\draw[thick][postaction={forze}] (a) -- (b) [load start] -- (c) [load end] -- (d);
% or
\draw[thick][postaction={forze,thin}] (a) -- (b) [load start] -- (c) [load end] -- (d);
```

bad result: the load appears to be thick too

```
\draw[preaction={draw,thick},postaction={forze}] (a) -- (b) [load start] -- (c) [load end] -- (d);
```

perfect result, but not transparent to the user (that should use the `preaction` key). So it seems that the second time that the path is used, it automatically gets the options from the first one (the manual says that the options are different, but it seems that this is true only if the same options are redefined). Is it possible to avoid this allowing to normally specify options on the path and just use `postaction={forze}` to draw the load (which can be easily made by a specific key)?

Comment: I guess you want to use the `preaction` and `postaction` options to reuse the path more than once. Also related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39242/define-tikz-macro-for-hatched-rectangles-in-local-coordinate-system

Comment: @percusse I updated the question with some considerations and trials. Thanks for the hint and for the related question (I really needed something like that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty here is that not all options are handled in the same way.  You can divide them roughly into "low" and "high", and into "immediate" and "delayed".

By low options I mean ones that set some TeX macro or similar.  These are things like setting the line width, the colour.  The basic style options.  High options are ones that set things up a bit more, like setting up postactions.

Immediate options are ones that are processed right at the moment they are invoked.  Delayed options are ones where the real setting part is done later (clearly something has to be done at the moment of invocation, but the real option is set later).  Line width is set right there and then, colour is delayed.

Another consideration is that many of the low-level styles, being controlled by TeX macros (or similar), obey TeX groupings.

With that in mind, the problem with your latest code is that you are setting the options on the main path and these last for the postaction path because it is in the same group and so these style options persist.  So if you want these not to apply to the postaction path, you need to save the style beforehand and then restore it within the postaction path.  But then you need to take into account the delay factor.

So the following code goes a little way towards this.  When the `forze` key is invoked, the style in force (currently the line width and the colour, but you could easily add more stuff) at that point is saved - but this might not be the style you think it is due to the delay on some options.  The safest thing is to use `forze` first on a path.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75904/86}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{load start/.style={insert path={coordinate
(mec@start@load)}},%
         load end/.style={insert path={coordinate (mec@end@load)}},
         load distance/.initial=1em,
         force distance/.initial=10pt,
         force length/.initial=.7cm,
         forze/.code={%
           \tikzset{
             save style=\forze@style,
             postaction={forze code},
           }
         },
         save style/.code={%
           \pgfutil@colorlet{forze@color}{.}%
           \edef#1{%
             line width=\the\pgflinewidth,
             color=forze@color,
           }
         },
         restore style/.code={%
           \expandafter\tikzset\expandafter{#1}%
         }
}
\tikzset{forze code/.code={%
    \message{got called}%
    \begin{scope}[restore style=\forze@style]%
    \coordinate (mec@X1) at
($(mec@start@load)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/load
distance}!90:(mec@end@load)$);
    \coordinate (mec@X2) at
($(mec@end@load)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/load
distance}!-90:(mec@start@load)$);
    \draw (mec@X1) -- (mec@X2);
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{mec@X1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{mec@X2}{center}}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mec@force@distrib@lenght}{veclen(\pgf@x,\pgf@y)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mec@force@number}{round(\mec@force@distrib@lenght/\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/force
distance})}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mec@force@distance}{1/\mec@force@number}
    \pgfmathparse{1-\mec@force@distance}
    \foreach \i in {0,\mec@force@distance,...,\pgfmathresult}{
      \coordinate (endarrow) at   ($(mec@X1)!\i!(mec@X2)$);
      \coordinate (startarrow) at
($(endarrow)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/force length}!90:(mec@X2)$);
      \draw[-latex] (startarrow) -- (endarrow);
    }
    \coordinate (endarrow) at   ($(mec@X1)!1!(mec@X2)$);
    \coordinate (startarrow) at ($(mec@X2)!\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/force
length}!-90:(mec@X1)$);
    \draw[-latex] (startarrow) -- (endarrow);
    \end{scope}
  }}%}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1mm]
\coordinate (a) at (0,0) node[left=of a]{A};
\coordinate (b) at (0,3) node[left=of b]{B};
\coordinate (c) at (3,3) node[right=of c]{C};
\coordinate (d) at (3,0) node[right=of d]{D};
\draw[forze,ultra thick,red] (a) -- (b) [load start] -- (c) [load end]
-- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1mm]
\coordinate (a) at (0,0) node[left=of a]{A};
\coordinate (b) at (0,3) node[left=of b]{B};
\coordinate (c) at (3,3) node[right=of c]{C};
\coordinate (d) at (3,0) node[right=of d]{D};
\draw[red,ultra thick,forze] (a) -- (b) [load start] -- (c) [load end]
-- (d);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This answers the question, indeed. So thanks a lot. But, how do you know about things like `\pgfutil@colorlet{}{}`? I can't find it in the manual! Is it necessary to read the low level TikZ code to know that? And the same question applies to the knowledge about the options. There is a "preferred way" to learn such things? Again, thanks

Comment: Another question: why the `postaction` key is in a `\tikzset` command (and some trials show that it needs to be there)?

Comment: @Spike I learn by looking at the code.  I don't know if there is an easier way.  For the second, oops.  The code went through several variations and so probably isn't the neatest.  Try removing the `\tikzset` and braces, and put `forze/.style=` instead of `forze/.code=`.  There was originally some non-trivial code in there but I moved it around.  I also notice that I've left a `\message` in there!

Comment: I should say that I don't think my code above is a very good implementation; it's more to highlight the things you need to think about when designing this.  In similar situations I've used an extra key which sets a default style for the extra paths explicitly.  Picking up on the ambient style is - as I tried to point out - problematic.  In such cases, I find it easier to just give control over to the user rather than try to anticipate all possible eventualities.

Comment: OK removing the `\tikzset` command and switching to a `style` everything is fine. With "preferred way" I didn't mean "easier" but  "suggested". Something like when you have to use a package, and you know that if you want to learn to use it you have to read the manual. By the way, reading the code is fine and interesting, so I'll try to do that. Thanks

Comment: There is a lot that's useful in the manual as well - even about the lower levels.  But when I need to figure out why a particular thing happens, then I find myself reading the source code.